# I am trying to bind a variable at the start of url on Curl, it is throwing error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, curl

```
curl \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST \
         $REPOSITORY_URL/engine-rest
```

http://10.195.177.141:31406 is binded to REPOSITORY_URL.

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: Make sure that the line continuation character (``\``) is the last character on each line - there should be no trailing space characters after it

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the variable with `${}`

```
curl \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST \
         ${REPOSITORY_URL}/engine-rest
```

Unless your URL has restrcited `curl` requests, the command will do as you expect it to, otherwise `curl` will only scrape error texts.

Comment: i tried doing that as well, when i echo it, i am able to see the url binded but still getting error.curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Comment: Could you give more info about your operating shell, `bash` or `zsh` and their versions? It works fine on mine.